# How can I show that a continuous map between covering maps is again a covering map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, covering-spaces

I have the following problem:

> Suppose $p:Y\rightarrow X$ and $p':Y'\rightarrow X$ are covering maps and $\phi:Y\rightarrow Y'$ is a continuous map s.t. $p'\circ \phi=p$. Suppose that $X,Y,Y'$ are connected and $X$ is also locally connected. Show that $\phi$ is a covering map.

> **Definition of a covering map** A continuous map $p:Y\rightarrow X$ is a covering map if forall $x\in X$ there exists an open neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ such that $p^{-1}(N)=\bigcup_\alpha N_\alpha$ where
>
> 1. $N_\alpha$ are open in $Y$
> 2. $N_\alpha\cap N_\beta=\emptyset$ if $\alpha \neq \beta$
> 3. $p|_{N_\alpha}:N_\alpha \rightarrow N$ is a homeomorphism

**Proof**

To check that $\phi$ is a covering map I need to show the following two points. First I need to check that $\phi$ is continuous, but this is trivially correct by the exercise. Now I need also to check the statements in the above definition. Therefore let $y'\in Y'$, then $p'(y')\in X$. Now since $p$ is a covering there exists an open neighbourhood $U\in \mathfrak{U}\left (p'(y')\right)$ such that $$p^{-1}(U)=\dot\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$$ where $U_\alpha$ are open in $Y$ and $p|_{U_\alpha}:U_\alpha \rightarrow U$ is a homeomorphism. Then clearly $$p'(y')\in U=\dot\bigcup_\alpha p\left(U_\alpha\right)\,\,\,\,\Leftrightarrow \,\,\,\,\,y'\in p'^{-1}\left(\dot\bigcup_\alpha p(U_\alpha)\right)=:N$$ where $N\in \mathfrak{U}(y')$ is open in $Y'$. Furthermore $$\phi^{-1}(N)=p^{-1}\left(p'(N)\right)=\dot\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$$ (thus point $1.,2.$ from the above definiton are satisfied). Now I only need to show that $$\phi|_{U_\alpha}:U_\alpha \rightarrow N$$ is a homeomorphism.

So my question is the following. Is the above part correct so? If yes could you give me a hint how to prove the homeomorphism part?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortuntaly your approach does not work. You have $p(U_\alpha) = U$ for all $\alpha$ and thus $N = (p')^{-1}(U)$. There is no reason to expect that $\phi|_{U_\alpha}:U_\alpha \rightarrow N$ is a homeomorphism. Take $Y' =Y$, $p' = p$ and $\phi = id$ to see what happens.